# In Microsoft Excel 2016, can I create a dropdown list in one workbook with the values from a column in a different workbook?

Tags: excel, validation, dropdown, excel-2016

I'm using Microsoft Excel 2016 and I have a workbook called "ProjectList.xlsx" that has a single column list of projects. What I want to do is that in another workbook, say "Project Status Tracker.xlsx", I'd like to have column A be a dropdown range, except that I want the values in that dropdown come from the "ProjectList.xlsx" workbook. Is this possible?

Thank you,
Sean

Comment: Yes of course. Have you looked into [Data Validation](http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html)?

Comment: As per my understanding, directly It is not possible to refer the data for a dropdown from other excel file. But indirectly it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, its not possible. Alternate approach can be copy the range to "ProjectList.xlsx" workbook. This range can reference to another workbook and then use Data Validation on this for the list.